# How can I keep rendering new pages of a large PDF as I scroll?

Tags: html, pdf, render

I have a 750-page PDF file and I want to embed it on my HTML page with ads on the sidebar. Unfortunately, the entire file gets loaded and it takes up to three minutes, which is not fast enough for my users. Also, that would make a lot of load on the server to load the file every time.

How can I load, let's say 25 pages, and then load more pages as the user scrolls?

Comment: What are you using to embed the PDF?  I don't believe there'll be an OOB way to do this, but depending on the software/framework you may have more options.  More likely than not though, it's going to involve splitting your PDF up into 25 page chunks and doing XHR requests when the user scrolls...

Comment: Is the PDF optimized for fast web view, and is byteserving active on the server?